# C# / WPF Events in Interface to Propagate to Other Classes

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am working on an application were we have several custom user controls in WPF (44 to be exact) that need to listen for an event that will be sent from a singleton object. I've thought about putting the event definition in an interface but not sure about the best way to wire up the delegate.

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface IOmegaModAdded
{
    event EventHandler OmegaModAdded;
}
```

How does interfaces like INotifyPropertyChanged do it?

Basically I need an event from the singleton object to be caught by any of the 44 user controls that may be instantiated.

I'm aware I can declare the delegate and event in the singleton object but is that really the best way to do it?

Comment: You need some sort of EventAggregator in your app. Take a look at Caliburn.Micro implementation https://joshearl.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/introduction-to-messaging-with-caliburn-micros-eventaggregator/ or at Messanger in MVVM Light, as they do exactly you wan to achieve.

Comment: @greyfox have you any kind of IOC container in your application?

Comment: @llan, unfortunately the team decided not to use IOC. I've used MVVM Light messaging in the past, just wasn't sure if this would be an appropriate use of it but sounds like its the right way to go